# How can I use two USB external hard drives by mirroring both like RAID 1

Tags: data-storage, raid, backup

I was using Amazone drive for store my photos and videos and important document etc.. by comparing the annual cost, now I'm thinking to move to a USB external hard drive because those files I'm not accessing so often and sometimes when I traveling cost for mobile data to download files are high.

My plan is to buy identical two USB external hard drives and use one as a storage and the other one as a backup. But I don't like the idea of mirroring as a schedule task by connecting both drives to a computer and using a mirror software.

Can I use some external hardware to do the mirror part same as RAID 1 concept. When files save in to a one drive, other drive also should get the same change. Something like a `hardware hub` or `splitter`.

As I feel this is a common requirement. Someone may achieve this before cloud storage get popular. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think RAID could be [configured with a USB hub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dougISKs2vQ) and then with [OS level software](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-combine-multiple-hard-drives-in-raid-0-using-windows-10s-storage-spaces-feature). Would you like a recommendation for a usb hub?

Comment: This is a interesting video. Looks like RAID configuration in the drives it self. I want to try this. Not sure this will works for the hard drives in Windows or Linux. Tnx for sharing!

Comment: [My second link](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-combine-multiple-hard-drives-in-raid-0-using-windows-10s-storage-spaces-feature) seems to suggest so for windows. [This link](https://www.tecmint.com/create-raid1-in-linux/) suggests this can be done on POSIX systems.

Comment: My suggestion would also be software RAID, unless you have some specific need for hardware RAID.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would probably be better solved with a software recommendation.

Comment: Software doesn't work I guess. because when I move around the portable hard drives and connected to other computers. those computers might not have the same RAID software installed.

Comment: I did that for a while (it's called "split-mirror RAID").  It doesn't work anywhere near as well as you'd imagine.

Answer (score 1):

You might look for a 2-Bay USB HDD case, for example the `LOGILINK UA0154A`.

There are plenty of casings around, see [Google Shopping](https://bit.ly/2C3M2Yr), but this depends on the size of your disks (2,5"; 3,5", ...). I would recommend two 2,5" SATA SSD's to get the best performance.

Edit: I really recommend to plug both drives to the same controller (let the "external hardware" do the RAID work for you).

Comment: Thank you so much. this is what I was looking for. I'm not able to see any casing which can support two WD my passport 4TB drives. https://www.pcworld.com/article/3178629/storage/wd-my-passport-4tb-review-a-good-budget-choice-thats-just-a-little-slow.html. Right now I don't have budget for SSDs :)